# Excel: calculate the amount - the numbers from a cell (58391) in another cell (5+8+3+9+1)

Tags: excel, windows, excel-formula, windows-10

I have an excel cell that contains the number 58391. Is there a formula that can count (calculate the amount) the numbers (5+8+3+9+1) in another cell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--MID(A1,ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(A1))),1))
```

The Mid returns an array of the numbers, by iterating the start position from the array of numbers that the ROW returns.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly modified approach to Scott's nice solution:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MID(A8,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A8))),1)*1)
```

The method is exactly the same, just a way of retrieving the starting position is different.

Comment: Just an FYI `INDIRECT` is volatile and by using that over the INDEX method it will force this formula to recalculate every time any changes are made in Excel whether to the target cell or any other cell in any open workbook in Excel.  With only one there would not be a noticeable lag on the calcs, but too many will cause a lag every time the user changes a cell.

Comment: Absolutely fair point - thanks @ScottCraner Agreed your solution is much more efficient for a larger data sets, just thought I will share this approach as a curiosity with fellow Excel enthusiasts. Cheers!

Comment: you may need to convert the numeric characters into actual numbers using `--` and there is probably no need to multiply 1 at the end.

Comment: Agreed @TerryW, thanks for pointing this out. I tend to use `--` and `*1` interchangeably.